# How to add information under pushpins in GoogleMAPS in android?

Tags: android, pushpin

I have been trying to solve one problem in my android app. I am using GoogleMAPS api in my app and I added some pushpins with using OverlayItem class.

But I want to add some information like "Central Park" , "Research Building" under all pushpins. I can only see this when I touch the pushin.But I wanna add these information under all pushpins.

I would be appreciated for any help.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using the google maps API V1 or V2?

Comment: I guess Its api version 1 , I have generated md5 fingerprint to work with these version 5 months ago. Im not sure which version It is

Comment: this is how I use overlay to add pushpin for baslangicNoktasi which is geopoint.I just want to write this info below the pushpin insted seeing it after touching the pushpin.

Comment: Drawable yesil = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pushpin_basla);

List<Overlay> mapOverlaysYesil = mapView.getOverlays();

OverlayOlustur overlayBaslangic = new OverlayOlustur(yesil, this); 
   baslangicNoktasi =new GeoPoint((int) (baslangicNoktaEnlem*1E6), (int) (baslangicNoktaBoylam*1E6));
        

OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(baslangicNoktasi,"info title","info text");


overlayBaslangic.addOverlay(overlayitem);
mapOverlaysYesil.add(overlayBaslangic);

Answer (score 0):

I am using google Maps api version 1.  and I am still trying to solve this problem.The codes below is what I am using for pushpins. I just want to see the info below the pushpins instead of seeing it after touching. I also want to add directing after touching the pushpin. Is that possible in version 1 ?

```
    Drawable green= this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pushpin);
    List<Overlay> mapOverlaysGreen = mapView.getOverlays();            

    OverlayOlustur overlayStart = new OverlayStart(green, this);      

    startPoint =new GeoPoint((int) (lat*1E6), (int) (lon*1E6));        
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(startPoint,"Info title","Info Text");         
    overlayBaslangic.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlaysGreen.add(overlayBaslangic);
```